# power series solution of $(x-3)y'+2y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Using power series, Find  solution of

> differential equation $(x-3)y'+2y=0$

What i try :: Let $\displaystyle y=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_{n}x^{n}.$ Then $\displaystyle y'=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}na_{n}x^{n-1}$

So we have $$(x-3)\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}na_{n}x^{n-1}+2\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_{n}x^{n}=0$$

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\bigg(na_{n}+2a_{n}\bigg)x^n+2a_{0}-3\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}na^{n}x^n=0$$

How do i solve it, Help me please, Thanks

Comment: Hint: Each term in the power series must be $0$, so you can solve for the $a_{n}$ individually.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your last equality. Somehow the $x^n$ have vanished in the first sum. Then try to arrange all terms so that you one power series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(x-3)y'+2y=0~~~~(1)$$
Its direct solution by separation of variables is $$y=\frac{C}{(x-3)^2}=\frac{C}{9}[1+2x/3+x^2/3+4x^3/27+5x^4/81+...]~~~~(2)$$
Here we have used binomial series $(1-z)^{-2}.$
Let us go for series solution near $x=0$ in powers of $x$, take
$$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n x^n~~~~(3)$$
Putting it in (1), we get (name of the summation idex is dummy)
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+2)A_n x^n-3\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}m A_m x^{m-1}~~~~(4)$$
Let $m-1=n$ in the second sum above, then (4) becomes
$$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+2) A_n x^n-3\sum_{n=-1} (n+1) A_{n+1} x^n~~~~(5)$$
$$\implies y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+2) A_n x^n-3\sum_{n=0} (n+1) A_{n+1} x^n~~~~(6)$$
$$\implies y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} [(n+2)A_n-3A_{n+1}] x^n=0=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 0 x^n~~~~(7)$$
$$\implies (n+2) A_{n}-3(n+1) A_{n+1}=0$$
$$\implies A_{n+1}=\frac{n+2}{3(n+1)}A_n, n=0,1,2,3,...~~~~(8)$$
$$\implies A_1=(2/3)A_0, A_2=(1/2)A_1,A_3=(4/9)A_2, A_4=(5/12)A_3,....~~~~~(9)$$
$$\implies A_1=(2/3)A_0, A_2=(1/3) A_0, A_3=(4/27)A+0,A_4=(5/81) A_0 ~~~~(10)$$
So finally from (3), we get
$$y(x)=A_0[[1+2x/3+x^2/3+4x^3/27+5x^4/81+...]~~~~(11)$$
Here, $A_0$ may be set as $C/9$. Finally (2) and (11) coincide.